# Unhandled expression arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to learn C++ and when I came to arrays it came up with this when trying to run this code:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00c3151f in array.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00390018`

this is the my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int array[8][8]; //Declares an array like a chessboard

    for ( x = 0; x < 8; x++ ) {
        for ( y = 0; y < 8; x++ )
            array[x][y] = x * y; // Set each element to a value
    }
    cout<<"Array Indices:\n";
    for ( x = 0; x < 8; x++ ) {
        for ( y = 0; y < 8; x++ )
            cout<<"["<<x<<"]["<<y<<"]="<< array[x][y] <<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger before asking.

Answer (score 4):

You need to increment `y` instead of `x` in:

```
for ( y = 0; y < 8; x++ )
                    ^ This should be y
```

(in both loops).

Comment: thanks something so simple